# How does SQL Server generate Guids?

Tags: sql-server, guid

I've supposed that Guids should have completely random values, but I've found the following IDs generated by SQL Server in my table:

```
15B308E5-FC37-E711-9C42-185E0F1C3427
52B09CEE-FC37-E711-9C42-185E0F1C3427
BE9553FF-FC37-E711-9C42-185E0F1C3427
BF9553FF-FC37-E711-9C42-185E0F1C3427
CE169E05-FD37-E711-9C42-185E0F1C3427
```

They do not seem to be random enough for me :)

So I'm just wondering, how does SQL Server generate those values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing that is documented about `NEWID()` is that it is [RFC4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the GUIDs in your example were generated with a [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql) default constraint. In that case, SQL Server uses the [UuidCreateSequential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API, along with some byte swapping to generate ordered GUID values that are sequential since the last computer restart.